# OpenFileDialog freez in QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, openfiledialog

When I open an open file dialog the first time everything works as it should, meaning the dialog opens and I can select a certain file. The problem I have is that each time I am trying to open an open file dialog **a second time** my whole program freezes. I have no idea why this is happening. I have debugged my program and I've seen that each time the program freezes at the `dialog.exec()` method. This issue started after I have upgraded my qt creator to version 5.8. I have also tried deleting the dialog instance each time I press a button and creating a new one, the result was the same. I include the header `#include < QFileDialog >`. Bellow you have my code posted.

```
QFileDialog *dialog;
dialog = new QFileDialog(this);
dialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
dialog->setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg *.bmp)"));

QStringList l;
QString file;
if (dialog->exec())
{
    l = dialog->selectedFiles();
    file = l.at(0);
  //do things with the file
    QMessageBox::information(this,"Image Loader","Image loaded successful");

}
```

If anyone knows how to solve this I would be grateful.